# Is there any difference between "receiver object" and "extension receiver"

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

It's hard to tell acording to the docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

so I wonder are **receiver object** and **extension receiver** the same? or does the name depends on context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *extension receiver* is a *receiver object* while a *receiver object* is either a *dispatch receiver* or an *extension receiver*.

> Inside a class, you can declare extensions for another class. Inside such an extension, there are multiple *implicit receivers* - objects members of which can be accessed without a qualifier. The instance of the class in which the extension is declared is called *dispatch receiver*, and the instance of the receiver type of the extension method is called *extension receiver*.
>
> ```
> class D {
>     fun bar() { ... }
> }
>
> class C {
>     fun baz() { ... }
>
>     fun D.foo() {
>         bar()   // calls D.bar
>         baz()   // calls C.baz
>     }
>
>     fun caller(d: D) {
>         d.foo()   // call the extension function
>     }
> }
> ```

In the above example the function `foo` has two *implicit receivers*: `C` is the *dispatch receiver* and `D` is the *extension receiver*. If `foo` were declared outside of `class C` then it would only have one receiver which would be the *extension receiver* `D`.

In short, a *receiver object* and an *extension receiver* can be the same but there is also another type of *receiver object* called a *dispatch receiver*.

For more details, see [Declaring Extensions as Members - Extensions - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members).

Comment: Thanks a lot this sentence makes everything clear for me "If foo were declared outside of class C then it would only have one receiver which would be the extension receiver D."